# Swift - Table View crashing on iPad, not crashing on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ipad

Pulling my hair out.

I've been running my application perfectly fine on the iPhone simulator's. But when I thought I was done, I ran it on the iPad, and my tableview is crashing. Please let me know if this is a bug, or if I code-blind to something simple.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row < 3 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCellSlider", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let keyLabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel
        let valueLabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(20) as? UILabel
        let slider = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(30) as! CustomSlider

        var value: Float = 0.0


        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            value = rate

            keyLabel?.text = "Rate"
            valueLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", rate) as String
            slider.minimumValue = AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate
            slider.maximumValue = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate
            slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsViewController.handleSliderValueChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

            slider.sliderIdentifier = 100

        case 1:
            value = pitch

            keyLabel?.text = "Pitch"
            valueLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", pitch) as String
            slider.minimumValue = 0.5
            slider.maximumValue = 2.0
            slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsViewController.handleSliderValueChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

            slider.sliderIdentifier = 200


        default:
            value = volume

            keyLabel?.text = "Volume"
            valueLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", volume) as String
            slider.minimumValue = 0.0
            slider.maximumValue = 1.0
            slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsViewController.handleSliderValueChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

            slider.sliderIdentifier = 300

        }

        if slider.value != value {
            slider.value = value
        }

    }else{

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCellVoicePicker", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }

    return cell
}
```

Slider Value Function

```
func handleSliderValueChange(sender: CustomSlider) {

    switch sender.sliderIdentifier {
    case 100:
        rate = sender.value

    case 200:
        pitch = sender.value

    default:
        volume = sender.value
    }

    tbSettings.reloadData()

}
```

CustomSlider Class

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    var sliderIdentifier: Int!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sliderIdentifier = 0
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        sliderIdentifier = 0
    }
}
```

I'm thinking it is some sort of bug, because again, it is running 100% perfectly on an iPhone, but crashing on an iPad.

Please help!

**UPDATE:** The crash reports says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I do not know what the nil value could be? What could be nil that isn't nil on an iPhone?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the crash report from the log??

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot, my apologies. Updated.

Comment: What line does the crash occur on?

Comment: Where do you set up the idCellSlider and the slider itself? It looks like the slider doesn't actually exist in the view which is why you're getting the error (I'm guessing the keyLabel and valueLabel don't exist either, but because you're not unwrapping them you're avoiding the error)

Comment: Wow, I don't even know how I made that mistake. Thank you so much.